# SpriteKit-based app not running on real device

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, ios-simulator, ios-provisioning

I just finished making my game with SpriteKit, and it runs perfectly fine on the simulators. When I connect my iPhone 5s to my computer and try to run it on my device, the app icon appears on my device but when I tap it all I get is a white screen. I set up all of my certificates, identifiers, and profiles. Is there something I was supposed to change in Xcode to make this work?

Comment: Put some NSLog() or println() methods in your appdelegate, viewcontroller, scene etc. and see if any of logs showing up.

Comment: I just tried that and no logs are showing up.